# SQL query getting data from 2 different database objects

Tags: sql-server

I am very much a beginner at more in depth SQL queries other then simple queries needed to more manage the server side then the database side so any help here is greatly appreciated.

I have a a database for a ticketing system where I need to take data from two different objects and combine the results into the results.

Looks something like this:

```
+Prof1
  - Columns
     *AssignedTech (tech assigned task)
     *Matters (unique matter ID)
     *Type (open, closed, development etc.)

+Matters
  - Columns
      *MatterNumber
```

What I am trying to do is get the Matter Number into the query like below but don't know other then perhaps dumping the results to Excel and filtering them from there to get that data into this query. Matters in the DBO corresponds to the unique Matter ID noted above. If i could even run the query below and then use those results to query against the Matters DBO to get the matter ID along with it.

```
select * 
from AssignedTech
where Type like 'open%'
order by Matters
```

Comment: Does `matters` have an id column?

Comment: Mureinik the first table (Prof1) Matters is a column under that Prof1 table where the 2nd Matters is a Table and the MatterNumber is a column under that Matters table. hope this makes sense

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample? It may make the question easier to understand

Comment: I posted an example below, but what I would like to get would be something where it queried if it was open first of all, otherwise do not include (comes from the type column in the dbo.Prof1 table) then if so it shows the Matter (unique number from the Matters column under the dbo.Prof1 Table) and the MatterNumber (from the MatterNumber column under the dbo.Matters table)

Comment: MatterNumber (from table Matters) and Matters (from table Prof1) are semantically equals?? (I mean both are Matter ID) ?

Comment: No, MatterNumber is a column under a Matter table whereas the Matter under the Prof1 table is a different column. if you look at the example image I put up you can see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you want to do is a SQL Join! (I suppose that the Column Matters at Prof1 Table is a reference to the MatterNumber at Matters Table)...

So, to do the join, you must write a query like this:

```
SELECT   A.*, B.MatterNumber
FROM     Prof1 A, Matters B
WHERE    A.Matters = B.MatterNumber AND A.Type like 'open%'
ORDER BY A.Matters;
```

Hope this help (also, that I understand you correctly)

Comment: Thanks Carlitos, im not sure I follow what you have here. I get the first Select and naming the both tables but lost on the where. How am i distinguishing the Matter column output from the  Prof1 table with the MatterNumber column from the Matters table? guess that's whats throwing me off.

Comment: A little explanation... when you write `FROM Prof1, Matters` your are doing a cartesian product between the tables, that means if Prof1 has 3 records and Matters has two records ... your select query will end up with 6 records (combining each record of Prof1 with each record of Matters) ... then, the where clause makes a filter... it says from the cartesian product, pick only those whose Prof1.Matters Column matches the Matters.MattersNumber ... Then, the select says picks all columns from the cartesian product

Answer (score -1):

Mureinik, I wish I could post a screenshot but hopefully this helps. The section of the DB Basically looks something like this

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxpOV.jpg)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxpOV.jpg]